# Tensorflow custom model weights are not getting updated with each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am new to Tensorflow and my currently making personal projects to gain experience.
At the moment, I'm trying to create a personal project based on the 2017 research paper 'An Unsupervised Neural Attention Model for Aspect Extraction.' The link to this paper is given [here](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/%7Eleews/publications/acl17.pdf). I have been heavily using the code mentioned in the Github repo of the researcher for the training part of this custom model. The link to her repo can be found [here](https://github.com/ruidan/Unsupervised-Aspect-Extraction/tree/master/code). It can be seen that weights aren't getting updated after each epoch. This is the [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10hWQH5ZJklmjpiNIwXuKJWQw9XanEy3_?usp=sharing) to my notebook. Kindly help me in solving this issue.
Also, can you please share the explanation as to why she defined the loss and the metric for this model as given below?

```
def max_margin_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_pred)

optimizer_ = Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=10, clipvalue=0)
my_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer_, loss=max_margin_loss, metrics=[max_margin_loss])
```

Is there a way to use the Hinge loss custom layer as the loss?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to use hinge loss function you can directly call it.

```
model.compile(loss='hinge', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But as per the research paper, I'm required to use a custom hinge loss as described in it. So, I'm unsure whether the default hinge loss will work in this specific case. But your mention of the metric seems to be reasonable.